# AudioQueueStart fails after a phone call in iphone4

Tags: ios, audioqueue

i'm trying to record from an app with AudioQueue in ios6 and iphone4, i've found that when last thing i've done with the phone is a call, then AudioQueueStart fails with (2003329396), and can't start input queue anymore.

Without the previous phone call, AudioQueueStart works well, multiple times.

This occurs in that way:

```
I do a phone call.
Start my app.
Creating unique audio session...
Creating session property listener...
Activating session...
Setting audio category... (Record)
Property listener received... 1919902568 kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange
Reason is: kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_CategoryChange 
Inputs avaliable (here Im looking in route dictionary information, if i have inputs     information in new route )
Creating new Queue Input...
Allocate/Enqueue queue buffers...
Start Record Queue...
OSStatus ERROR (2003329396)
```

This seems not affect iphone4s.

Is there any normal way to recover the ability to use AudioQueueStart for an input queue, in this case?

Thanks, sorry for my format...

Comment: Something is wrong with audio category, i set the category to record, get category, and is set to record. But when start the input queue fails (under contidions above). When it fails, if i set category to play, then back to record, input queue starts well again. Happy to found this! but weird... isn't?

Comment: An ugly retry worked for me, without recreating queue, if AudioQueueStart for an input queue fails, i set the category to play, then to record again, and call AudioQueueStart now working... :)

Comment: Amazingly, this hack works! thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle Audio Interruptions
Read the following documentation

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html

Comment: I was already handling interruptions, but i this case, call start and ends before the app begins, no interruptions are involved, i think. The session was active. Sorry i didn't mention the interruption callback registration and session test in traces. But thank you I didn't reach that particular document I think. I will read if I can handle this better. But seems an inconsistent state for AudioQueue services, apple's interrumptions example fails too, maybe was old. At least seems to return services with that redundant change in category. Maybe i'm missing something, i will read this thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem here.

I ended up ignoring this specific error-code on devices identifying as iPhone 4.
My queue starts normally despite the error code.